# Folium templatesyntaxerror

Tags: python, folium, geopy

I'm trying to visualize geo-data of dataframe of tweets on a map using the Folium and geopy libraries of Python. This is my code:

```
def get_location():
location_data = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['geo.country']:
            location_data.append((row['author.name'], row['geo.country_code']))
return location_data
```

then i use geopy to get [longitude, lattitude]

```
def put_markers(map, data):
geo_locator = Nominatim(user_agent="LearnPython", timeout=10)
for (name, location) in data:
    if location:
        try:
            location = geo_locator.geocode(location)
        except GeocoderTimedOut:
            continue
        if location:
            folium.Marker([location.latitude, location.longitude], popup=name).add_to(map)

map = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], zoom_start=2)
location_data = get_location()
put_markers(map, location_data)
map.save("index.html")
```

the program runs normally until the map.save instruction, it gives the following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.templatesyntaxerror: expected token ':', got '}'
```

what does it mean? and how to solve this problem? thanks for your help.

Comment: What line is the error referring to? I don't see a "}" anywhere in your code.

Comment: the code put the markers on the map successfully. and when it passes to the map.save instruction it outputs this error. I think the code is fine.